# How can make django don't create id column for database table

Tags: mysql, django, database

I'm using **django** to create database tables for **mysql**,it works well,but i noticed that it create `id` column for each table,that's not I want,so can I disable this default behaviour,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ask django NOT to create an `id` field automatically.

According to [this documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

Just create any other field with primary_key=True in your model.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should point `primary_key = True` to the suitable field in your model.
So the `id` field will be substitued by that field.

Answer (score 1):

add **primary_key = True** to your unique field and you will get rid from id field .